# Alias for sudo then ssh

Tags: bash, alias, bash-alias

I am looking to write an alias for the following two command:

```
sudo su - user
ssh somewhere
```

I've tried

```
alias jump='sudo su - user; ssh '
```

and then use this as

```
jump somewhere
```

but this doesn't work. Are there any options or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm working with a legacy system where the user we login with doesn't have permission to ssh. But that user has permission to switch to another admin type (not root) user and then jump to other boxes. I know it doesn't sound good but I'm not able to change this. I always need to type the 2 commands above and was just looking to have a one liner instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ssh` will run after the `sudo su` finishes, that's why your way doesn't work. If you are allowed to run `sudo ssh` then this will probably work:

```
alias jump='sudo -u user ssh '
jump somewhere
```

---

Alternatively `su -c`. It doesn't allocate tty, but `ssh -tt` can force it. I'm not sure everything will work right though. Alias would require some heavy quoting & escaping frenzy, it's way easier with a function:

```
function jump { sudo su - -c 'ssh -tt "$@"' user su "$@"; }
jump somewhere
```

Don't forget to `unalias jump`, if the alias is still defined.

Comment: nice, but unfortunately ssh isn't allowed. I get this: Sorry, user <my-username> is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/ssh somewhere' as <other-username> on current-box

Comment: yes, I can't run command as the other user. But I can switch to it and then run the commands. Strange -_-

Comment: @sttaq See my expanded answer.